# Springfuse - Failed to execute goal: generate

Tags: spring-mvc

I try to generate an Eclipse Project with Springfuse code generator, based on a MySql database. I have filled up the form at http://www.springfuse.com/, and it generated following Maven command:

mvn -U archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.springfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.108 -DgroupId=com.company.demo -Dpackage=com.company.demo -DartifactId=myproject -Dversion=1.0.0 -DfrontEnd=jsf2Spring -Demail=peter.varga.sp@gmail.com -Dpassword=none -DjdbcGroupId=mysql -DjdbcArtifactId=mysql-connector-java -DjdbcVersion=5.1.25 -DjdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -DjdbcUser=root -DjdbcPassword=qwe123 -DjdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeRepository=http://maven2.springfuse.com/

I opened a command window, copied the command as it is, and run it, but got following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.springfuse.archetypes:quickstart:3.0.108) -> [Help 1]

My environment details:

Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
Maven home: c:\Prog\Maven\Maven.3.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Does anybody has an idea, what the problem is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the settings of proxy / firewall springfuse. Also check the Apache Maven, because it needs to download the dependencies on the Internet. And if it fails, then its usually you need to tell him about the http proxy you need to use.